# In MySQL how should I alter my syntax to add a 'WHERE' clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, mysql-error-1054

Example:

```
SELECT s.title, t.description,
u1.value * s.cache_value as Cache,
u2.value * s.drive_value as Drive,
u3.value * s.error_value as Error,
u3.value * s.error_value + u3.value * s.error_value as ErrorHigh,
u3.value * s.error_value - u3.value * s.error_value as ErrorLow,
m.area
FROM storage s
JOIN status t on t.id = s.status_id
JOIN manufac m on m.id = s.area
JOIN unit u1 on s.cache_unit_id = u1.id
JOIN unit u2 on s.drive_unit_id = u2.id
JOIN unit u3 on s.error_unit_id = u3.id
```

Desired goal:

```
SELECT s.title, t.description,
u1.value * s.cache_value as Cache,
u2.value * s.drive_value as Drive,
u3.value * s.error_value as Error,
u3.value * s.error_value + u3.value * s.error_value as ErrorHigh,
u3.value * s.error_value - u3.value * s.error_value as ErrorLow,
m.area
FROM storage s
JOIN status t on t.id = s.status_id
JOIN manufac m on m.id = s.area
JOIN unit u1 on s.cache_unit_id = u1.id
JOIN unit u2 on s.drive_unit_id = u2.id
JOIN unit u3 on s.error_unit_id = u3.id
WHERE 123 BETWEEN ErrorHigh AND ErrorLow;
```

**MySQL returns syntax Error unknown column ErrorHigh**

*Note: `ErrorHigh` and 'ErrorLow` are the the new columns I create to display the computed values*

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197215/fighting-inner-join-unknown-column-when-trying-to-avoid-a-repeated-stored-func/9197376#9197376

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1054 error is because SQL doesn't support referencing column aliases in the WHERE clause - the earliest MySQL supports is the `GROUP BY`.  But most other databases only support column aliases in the `ORDER BY` clause.

If you want to continue to use the column alias, the operation it represents needs to be performed in a subselect, derived table/inline view.  Otherwise, you can replace the column alias with the operation it represents - like this:

```
WHERE 123 BETWEEN u3.value * s.error_value + u3.value * s.error_value 
              AND u3.value * s.error_value - u3.value * s.error_value
```

Comment: ah.. ok. Thank you so much OMG Ponies

Comment: example and explanation of the subselect approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197215/fighting-inner-join-unknown-column-when-trying-to-avoid-a-repeated-stored-func/9197376#9197376